# Angular-2 : Change favicon icon as per configuration

Tags: angular, favicon

I am rendering a dynamic page, menu and other items in my application.
I also want to change favicon as per configured by admin.

Say, for example, if when my **page load** configured favicon is `xyz.png` then it will show `xyz.png` as the favicon.

As in the below image, new favicon should replace existing one near by "Test Application". Right now, it shows the default favicon as seen below.

[image: Default favicon]

---

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/MyFirstAngular2/" >
    <title>Angular 2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" id="appIcon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main/reflect-metadata.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/system.config.js"></script>
    <script>

        document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG.map.app = 'scripts/configs';

        document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG.packages.app = { main: 'application.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' };

        System.config(document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG);

        System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });        
    </script>

</head>
<body>
        <application></application>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I get a new favicon on every component load, so you have to just change favicon icon from any component call.

Comment: What build scheme do you use?  Your question is too generic without html code that you have

Comment: @Shershen: i have updated html, please refer it

Comment: I wrote a whole piece here on this by using Angular's build system to do it properly https://medium.com/@benracicot/favicons-for-each-environment-327f5b832bae

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './path/to/app.component';
import {AppService} from './path/to/app.service';
// ....

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

`app.service.ts`

```ts
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument, private http:Http) 
    getAppDetails(appId: string) {

            return this.http.post(url, appId)
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    let details = response.json();
                    return details;
                })
                .do(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

     private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

    setAppFavicon(id: string, basepath: string, icon: string){
       this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', basepath+"/"+ icon);
    }
}
```

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AppService} from "../path/to/app.service";


@Component({
    selector: 'application',
    templateUrl: './path/to/app.component.html'
})
export class ApplicationComponent {

    details: any;

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {

        this.details = appService.getAppDetails(id);
        appService.setAppFavicon(id,basepath,this.details.icon);

    }


}
```

Comment: cant believe this answer receives so many votes while it is suggesting mod the dom with jquery

Comment: Absolutely. Angular has many DOM related engines to do just this. NEVER use jQuery.

Comment: **NEVER use jQuery in Angular** you should not manipulate DOM outside of Angular component life-cycle

Comment: getting the data without subscribing to the service method getAppDetails(), and passing it directly to the setAppFavIcon(). what if the endpoint is taking time to return the results.

Answer (score 55):

In index.html set link tag

```
<link id="appFavicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

and somewhere in your code import

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument) {}
```

and use it like this

```
this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', '/your/icon/path.ico');
```

**Angular 5.0 <**

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Comment: import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use the correct import like @fdsfdsfdsfds recommends.

Comment: Thank You @Verri!! Was searching for a while before finding this and it works perfect across Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 (need to support for client).
Our setup is running through CircleCI so the circle-ci.xml config is setting the base-href to something diff for each environment.

Comment: This solution works fine but for **Angular 8.0 or >**

    `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';`

Answer (score 3):

Worked well, no injections, no worries, simple code. But it's gonna be a pure javascript in your angular project.

```js
document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', '/your/icon/path.ico');
```

Answer (score 1):

We have nodejs running in the back-end, we have URL specific favicon to display as a requirement.

In app.js we implemented a `resolveConfig()` function which will help us to get the url specific configuration.

The return value of above function is used in get favicon call as below.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/favicon.ico',(req,res)=> {
   let key = resolveConfig(req.hostname);
   switch (key) {
     case 'a':
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/assets/a.ico');
       break;
     case 'b':
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/assets/b.ico');
       break;
   }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

*this might be useful if you have a nodejs in backend.

Answer (score -2):

Then you can use javascript to set favicon per configuration by adding following function to your `<script>` block:

```html
 <script>

        document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG.map.app = 'scripts/configs';

        document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG.packages.app = { main: 'application.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' };

        System.config(document.SYSTEMJS_CONFIG);

        System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });        

//here favicon is set
(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = '../path/to/xyz.png'; //path to selected favicon file
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());

    </script>
```

Comment: It should be set from component, because i get new icon in compenent and it will dynamic by page

Answer (score -6):

Outside `<application></application>`, you can to use only [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) class:

```ts
import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class YourClass(){

  constructor(private title: Title){}

  yourNameMethod(){
    this.title.setTitle('your title');
  }
}
```

Comment: I have set title already, as you can see in image, now i wants to set favicon icon, can you please help me regarding that