# Build the same angular project several times with different styles into the same dist folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 11 project which has to be deployed to 4 different corporate domains with 4 different styling.

My idea is to configure angular build command to pack all assets, vendors, app javascript files into dist folder and then compile 4 different scss and add to the same dist folder. offcourse there should be 4 index files that reference appropriate css.

after that different domain can point to the same folder but different index files.

The advantage of this construction is in build/deploy speed

Can this be achieved with angular cli configuration?

thank you.

Comment: If the layout is almost the same across all 4 domains, but only fonts/colors/sizes differ, than I think it would be better to create themes for your project. And apply necessary theme based on domain

Comment: @vitaliy kotov, thats might be it, but i cant find anything like that in angular cli documentation... or you suggest to build it manually?

Comment: It doesn't affect build process anyhow, it's just an approach which allows you to support few themes. You can take a look [here, for example](https://coryrylan.com/blog/theming-angular-apps-with-css-custom-properties) how to make it with CSS Variables.

Comment: @vitaliy kotov, theming is great! thx. but how to use different assets in index files now? like favicons.
it has to become dynamic somehow so based on domain i can use different assets...

Comment: You can create a folder for each domain inside your assets folder and use relative path to them in css vars. Regarding favicon, you can set it dynamically like it's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753615/11900833) and there is a built in [Title service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) for setting title of the tab